# Hibernate adds a column that does not exist in select

Tags: hibernate

I have entity class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "ktp_vats_affiliate", schema = "ktp")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "seq_vats_affiliate_seq", schema = "ktp", allocationSize = 1)
public class VatsAffiliate extends VersionedEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2390179214465024152L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    protected Long id;
    @Column(name = "MRF_NAME")
    private String mrfName;
    @Column(name = "AFFILIATE_NAME")
    private String affiliateName;
    @Column(name = "X_TERR_REF_ID")
    private String xTerrRefId;
    @Column(name = "CITY_NAME")
    private String cityName;
    @Column(name = "CITY_ID")
    private String cityId;
}
```

Create table script is:

```
create table KTP_VATS_AFFILIATE
(
    ID             number        not null,
    MRF_NAME       varchar2(128) not null,
    AFFILIATE_NAME varchar2(128) not null,
    X_TERR_REF_ID  varchar2(128),
    CITY_NAME      varchar2(128) not null,
    CITY_ID        varchar2(128) not null
);
-- Create/Recreate indexes
-- Constraint and sequence
```

Also i have CRUD repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface VatsAffiliateRepository extends CrudRepository<VatsAffiliate, Long> {
}
```

When i call repository.findOne(id) method throws "Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "VATSAFFILI0_"."INLOCK": invalid identifier". Hibernate create select with column "INLOCK" that doesn't exist, what can be a problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Alter your table and add primary key like `ID             number        not null primary key`

Comment: I already have this constraint.

Comment: Try changing column name `ID` to `myID` or something like this.

Comment: Thank you, Sudhir for your help. It is my mistake i found problem in extended class.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, i found the problem it;is not in Hibernate. This class "VersionedEntity" has field inlock.